# Split partition with Ubuntu 13.04 and windows 7

Tags: partitioning

How do I split the partition without loosing my windows OS and files .I am mainly concerned about the new table.

Answer (score 0):

## From my experience:

### Make a note of how much "stuff" you've installed on your hard drive. In GB

### You should install Ubuntu, but stop when it tells you "Partition Disks"

#### Choose Manual Partition. YOU MUST UNMOUNT your drives.

#### Then from the list of partitions, select your HardDrive. It is usually as big as the advertized size.

#### Edit the size and make sure the size at least more than your current occupied space.

ie: 250/500 Gb, resize: 300 GB.

#### Then, after you follow its directions, it should let you save and create a separate partition.

Then, you change the new partition (probably called sd5) and create a split partition of around 4GB RAM. Just do the same as you did previously.

#### After you are done, you should have create 2 separate partitions.

#### You will use these partitions.

**Select the bigger partition that you created - NOT the one labeled ntsf. You want to edit it. Then change from "do not use" or what option there is to "ext2", "ext3", or "ext4". This is the first option from the editor. Save. **

### Next, select the smallest partition that you created. It should be the last partition (ie sda6).

You want to edit it. Then change from "do not use" or what option to "swap". This is your "RAM". Not really, but it is recommended.

**MAKE SURE that all other partitions are unchanged and marked "do not use". **

### Next save and continue. It will then ask if it can format the disks. You must format your 2 partitions. And that is where Ubuntu will install the OS.

Continue thus from.